# How can i set the Columnname of my Datagrid dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I read some data from a datagrid, named dgTable2(3 Columns, unknown Rows). After that, i want to make for every row inside dgTable2, a new column inside dgTable3 and as headername i want to set the first parameter of dgTable2 (column 0 in all rows).
My Problem is to add a new DatagridColumn dynamically.

Here my Code:

```
private void LoadDataToMaschine_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgTable1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        dgTable3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        int anzZeilen = tableSelectedVar.Rows.Count;

        string[,] inhaltVar = new string[anzZeilen, 3];

        //read all data from table to array
        for (int i = 0; i <= anzZeilen-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                inhaltVar[i, j] = tableSelectedVar.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
            }
        }

        //create a new table for the Data
        DataTable tableforDataStream = new DataTable();
        //Should create a datagridcolumn and add a tableColumn
        for (int k = 0; k <= (inhaltVar.GetLength(0)-1); k++)
        {
            //Erstellt die Columns für jeden Parameter

            dgTable3.Columns.Add(inhaltVar[k,0]);
            tableforDataStream.Columns.Add(inhaltVar[k, 0]);
        }
        dgTable3.ItemsSource = tableforDataStream.DefaultView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple as f... :D

```
DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn(); 
textColumn.Header = "Header"; 
textColumn.Binding = new Binding("BindingValue"); //only if you want to bind data to it
dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
```